# HIbernate Envers @AuditMappedBy cause SQLException: Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

in my project I use hibernate Envers (v. 4.3.7) with Spring and MySql (v. 5.6.25) for auditing some entities.

This is my example:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket implements java.io.Serializable {

    ....

    private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>(0);

    ....

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ticket")
    @AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "ticket")
    public List<Payment> getPayments() {
        return this.payments;
    }

    public void setPayments(List<Payment> payments) {
       this.payments= payments;
    }
    ...
}


@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment")
public class Payment implements java.io.Serializable {

    ....

    private Ticket ticket;
    private Long ticketId;


    ....

    @Column(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false)
    public Long getTicketId() {
         return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(Long ticketId) {
         this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Ticket getTicket() {
        return this.ticket;
    }

    public void setTicket(TktTicket ticket) {
        this.ticket= ticket;
    } 

   ......
}
```

When try to insert a new Ticket the the system return the exception:

**org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
.....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (19 > number of parameters, which is 18)**

Some idea?

Comment: You have an error in your index of database, you can change your index then try to insert again, good luck

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example? I did not understand your comment. Tanks.

Comment: Test this and if not succes ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 20;    ELSE how paramettre do you have in your entities?

Comment: Hi, if i remove the annotation @AuditMappedBy from Ticket class, the audit tables are correctly filled (inser and/or update ticket). But if a try to retrieve the old revisions I get this error:
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ticketId_id of: it.edea.ferrycloud.dao.entity.Payment_AUD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved. Into Payment class I modified the reference to Ticket:

Old code:

```
@Column(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false)
public Long getTicketId() {
     return ticketId;
}

public void setTicketId(Long ticketId) {
     this.ticketId = ticketId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Ticket getTicket() {
    return this.ticket;
}

public void setTicket(TktTicket ticket) {
    this.ticket= ticket;
}
```

New code:

```
    @Column(name = "TKT_TICKET_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Long getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(Long ticketId) {
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TKT_TICKET_ID", nullable = false)
    public TktTicket getTktTicket() {
        return this.tktTicket;
    }

    public void setTktTicket(TktTicket tktTicket) {
        this.tktTicket = tktTicket;
    }
```

I removed the "insertable = false, updatable = false" from getTktTicket() and added to getTicketId(). Maybe this is a bug of Envers.